# how to get the query result in to two different arrays while plotting a Bar chat using flotcharts

Tags: php, arrays, flot

i have a problem in getting query result into two different arrays.
my requirement is like this

```
[[1,3],[2,8],[3,4],[4,1],[5,0],[6,8]]
[[1,"app1"],[2,"app2"],[3,"app3"],[4,"app4"],[5,"app6"],[6,"app6"]]
```

this is the format of data i needed to plot bar chart with labels on x-axis.I am trying like this
PHP Code

```
mysql_select_db($database_finalkms, $finalkms);
$query_getmaincatdetails = "SELECT `EquipmentMainCatagory`,count(EquipmentMainCatagory) FROM `assetinfo` group by EquipmentMainCatagory";
$getmaincatdetails = mysql_query($query_getmaincatdetails, $finalkms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getmaincatdetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmaincatdetails);
$totalRows_getmaincatdetails = mysql_num_rows($getmaincatdetails);
```

now i need to get the data from this query as shown in the above format to get the bar chart.
i am trying this

```
$rows = array();


         for ($i = 1; $i <=$totalRows_getmaincatdetails ; $i++) {

         foreach($row_getmaincatdetails as $r){
          $rows[] = array( $i,(int)$r[$row_getmaincatdetails['count(EquipmentMainCatagory)']]); 

           }


       }
    // convert data into JSON format
    $jsonTable = json_encode($rows);

    print_r($jsonTable);
```

I am not able to get data in the mentioned format.Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looping over the rows with both an iterator i and a foreach.  Simplify it with:

```
$getmaincatdetails = mysql_query($query_getmaincatdetails, $finalkms) or die(mysql_error());

var $i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmaincatdetails))
{
    $cats[] = array( $i,(int)$row['EquipmentMainCatagory']);
    $data[] = array( $i,(int)$row['count(EquipmentMainCatagory)']);        
    $i += 1;
}

$jsonTable = json_encode(array("data" => $data, "cats" => $cats));

etc...
```

Back in your JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON("some.php", function(json) {

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [
        {
            data: json['data'],
            bars: {
                 show: true
            }
         }
    ], {
        xAxis: {
            ticks: json['cats']
        }
    });
});
```

My Standard PHP disclaimer:  I don't like PHP, I don't use PHP, code is untested...